# Swagger definition for custom connector to trigger databricks jobs in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, swagger-2.0, powerapps-canvas, power-apps-custom-connector

I have implemented a swagger api definition for custom connector to trigger databricks jobs from Power apps.
https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/jobs/runnow

```
  /run-now:
    post:
      responses:
        default:
          description: default
          schema: {}
      summary: run-now
      description: Run a databricks job
      operationId: run_now
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              job_id:
                type: string
                description: job_id
              job_parameters:
                type: object
                additionalProperties: true
                description: job_parameters
```

For job_parameters, I defined additionalProperties: true so that it can accept any datatype.

Later I tried to integrate my custom connector in my canvas app in Power apps with this function:
`'DatabricksJobsAPI2.1'.runnow({job_id: 86726485724569, job_parameters: {document_ids: "41d0dhtf7-4995-4a00-a972-71598765d9b67"}})`
DatabricksJobsAPI2.1 is my custom connector name.
**Error: job_parameters expects "UntypedObject" but provided "Record" type**.
It should work according to swagger definition but it is not accepting any data type.

But when I test my custom connector in "test" tab it worked well. But in canvas app with functions it is not working. I do not want to use Power automate- for this process. I should only use functions. Is there any other method I should update my swagger definition?.

I wanted to implement this swagger to be not specific job related. It should trigger for any databricks job by assigning manually necessary job_parameters within function but not in Swagger.